# Combinations Function - Objective-C (OS X vs Ubuntu)

Tags: objective-c, ubuntu-16.04, macos-high-sierra

I have a function written in Objective-C that should return the combinations using a set based on the length. This function has been tested on the Mac (OS X) and Ubuntu (16.04). The code will miss combinations if executed on the Mac but returns all combinations if executed under Ubuntu. This only presents an issue if the number of objects in the set is greater than 6. What is the difference from using Objective-C on both Platforms?

Compilers/IDE/OS
Xcode 9.2 macOS High Sierra version 10.13.3
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) 5.4.0 20160609

Here is the code used on both systems.

```
//C5GenCombo.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface C5GenCombo : NSObject
{
}

- (NSSet*) combinationsOfSize :(NSUInteger)size :(NSSet*)thisSet;
- (void) loadCombinations;

@end

// C5GenCombo.m
#import "C5GenCombo.h"

@implementation C5GenCombo

- (void) loadCombinations
{       
     NSSet *combinationSet;

     NSArray *testArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"1", @"2", @"6", @"14", @"16", @"19", @"21", nil];

     combinationSet = [self combinationsOfSize :5 :[[NSSet alloc] initWithArray:testArray]];

     NSLog(@"%ld\r\n",[combinationSet count]);
}

- (NSSet*) combinationsOfSize :(NSUInteger)size :(NSSet*)thisSet
{   
    NSMutableSet *newSet = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithSet:thisSet];

    if (size == 0){
        return [NSSet setWithObjects:[NSMutableSet set],nil];
    }

    if ([newSet count] == 0){
        return newSet;
    }

    NSSet* retVal;

    NSMutableSet* tail = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithSet:newSet];

    id head = [tail anyObject];

    [tail removeObject:head];

    NSMutableSet* subSet = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithSet:[self combinationsOfSize:(size - 1):tail]];

    for (NSMutableSet* i in subSet){
        [i addObject:head];
    }

    [subSet unionSet:[self combinationsOfSize:size:tail]];

    retVal = [[NSSet alloc] initWithSet:subSet];

    return retVal;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Which framework are you using on Linux? GNUStep? GNUStep does some things different from Foundation on Darwin — one thing I vaguely recall off the top of my head is that their implementation of `anyObject` returns objects differently from how Foundation does it, which your algorithm may be depending on.

Comment: What combinations are missed? What have you done to debug this? What are the values of various variables as you step through your code? Why did you declare both `newSet` and `tail`? Etc. You get the idea. Edit your question and provide details, what you've tried, what you discovered, where you got stuck, etc.; that will enable people to help you.

Comment: Yes, I am using GNUStep on Linux. I did debug the statement around anyObject but it appear to load the values that are remaining in the set that is evaluated at the time. The missing Combinations are (1 2 3 4 6), (1 2 4 6 7), (2 4 5 6 7). The only hard part about debugging is that the sets are not ordered the same on both systems at the time of execution. Unlike arrays, sets can be arranged in any order. I declared newSet and tail to retain the original values. During my initial development without newSet the program returned an empty set which I know is not possible to have an empty set.